How to Replace URLs with Buttons in wpDataTables Plugin in WordPress?
I'm working with the wpDataTables plugin on a WordPress site and trying to replace URLs with buttons in one of my tables. Specifically, I have columns that contain Instagram and YouTube links, and I want these to appear as "Open" buttons that, when clicked, open the link in a new tab.
I added the following function to my functions.php file to try and replace the links with buttons:
add_action('wp_footer', 'custom_wpdatatables_modifications', 100);

function custom_wpdatatables_modifications() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // Select all tables within the wrapper (adjust wrapper class if necessary)
            $('.table_1_wrapper').each(function() {
                // Within each table, find Instagram and YouTube links and modify them
                $(this).find('td.column-instagram a, td.column-youtube a').each(function() {
                    var link = $(this).attr('href'); // Get the URL
                    var platform = $(this).closest('td').hasClass('column-instagram') ? 'Instagram' : 'YouTube';

                    // Replace the existing link with a button link
                    $(this).replaceWith('<a href="' + link + '" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Open ' + platform + '</a>');
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}

After deploying this code, the links still appear as plain URLs in the table.
Why are the URLs not being replaced by buttons, and how can I ensure the links are properly replaced by the buttons? Is there a better approach for modifying the content of the table rows generated by wpDataTables?
Thank you very much for any help!:)
I reviewed the documentation of the wpDataTables plugin and found that there is an option to display links as buttons. However, when I enable this feature and export the table, the exported file shows the button label (e.g., "Open") instead of the actual URL. I want the buttons to be displayed in the table but retain the correct link format in exports. To solve this, I tried replacing the links with custom buttons using JavaScript, but it hasn't worked as expected.

Just an update - managed to fix it:)
